# How to automatically count amount of cards in Trello?

Tags: trello-cards

How to automatically count amount of cards? In some list, or in the board.

Answer (score 67):

Click on show menu on the right side of the board if its not visible.

From the Menu option select Search Cards.

In the text box type `*` to "filter by everything".

All cards will remain visible and you'll also get card counts at the top of each list.

[image: Screenshot]

This only works in the web version of Trello.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is keep the filter "*" on.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [List Limits](https://trello.com/power-ups/5c2462c384ab8949b1724a20/list-limits) extension (Power-Up), it will count them for you. You have to add a maximum limit of cards the list can have, and it will show as ACTUAL_NUMBER / MAX

[image]